# How do I trigger a Github Action on project card movement?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-projects

I need a Github action which closes an issue when that issue is moved to a "Done" column on a Github Project.

My issue is that the `project_card` trigger only works on "classic" projects. Github specifies this [in their documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#project_card) for the `project_card` trigger: *"This event only occurs for projects (classic)."*

I would use a classic project, but unfortunately Github has made it so classic projects [cannot be created for repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/organizing-your-work-with-project-boards/managing-project-boards/creating-a-project-board) unless that repo has an existing classic project. I assume this is to phase out classic projects, which is fine except for triggers like `project_card` which only work with them.

Hoping there is some form of solution for `project_card` trigger to work with non-classic Github projects in the interim?

I tried using this [Github Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/issue-states) with a non-classic project, but the action uses the `project_card` trigger which led me to this issue.

Comment: You may explore the `github` context to identify the event. Maybe, something like `echo '${{ toJSON(github.event) }}' >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` would help to see if there's such an event or not. Though, I'm not sure how this would be triggered for non-classic projects. You might have some idea of how to do that as you've been working with project-related events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old and unfortunately this answer is a non-answer.

I recently ran into this issue, since GitHub now disabled creating classic projects. You're right, it looks like the new projects do not trigger `project_card` like classic projects did. In my opinion, this is a huge overlook on GitHub's part. I have opened a discussion about it: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/62113